# can't add the Dynamic values in Pie Carts

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
//
//  PieChartTest.m
//  Yazaki
//
//  Created by apple on 3/25/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 apple. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PieChartTest.h"

#import "testingvc.h"
@interface PieChartTest ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *values;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *testARYY;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *labels;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *colors;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL inserting;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *colors1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *serviceResponse;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *item;
@property(strong,nonatomic)  NSArray *temp;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *sample;
@end

@implementation PieChartTest
@synthesize dictObject;
@synthesize str1;
@synthesize str2;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.122:8099/YazakiService.svc/SESSION/%@/%@/%@",dictObject,str1,str2];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLResponse *response;


    NSError *error;


    NSData *responseData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

  _serviceResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSArray *temp =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];
    NSDictionary *sample=[temp objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString*item=[sample objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"];


    if( [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"] == nil ||
       [[_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ){
        // do nothing
    }else
    {
        NSArray *temp =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];
        if ([temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && temp.count !=0)

        {
            // value is available
            [self.values removeAllObjects];
            self.values = [NSMutableArray new];
            int i;

            for (i=0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
                [self.values addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"]]];
                [self.values addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"SESSIONVALUE"]]];
            }

        }
    }


   self.pieChartView.dataSource = self;
    self.pieChartView.delegate = self;
    self.pieChartView.animationDuration = 0.5;
    self.pieChartView.sliceColor = [MCUtil flatWetAsphaltColor];
    self.pieChartView.borderColor = [MCUtil flatSunFlowerColor];
    self.pieChartView.selectedSliceColor = [MCUtil flatSunFlowerColor];
    self.pieChartView.textColor = [MCUtil flatSunFlowerColor];
    self.pieChartView.selectedTextColor = [MCUtil flatWetAsphaltColor];
    self.pieChartView.borderPercentage = 0.01;


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSlicesInPieChartView:(MCPieChartView *)pieChartView {


    return self.values.count;
}
- (CGFloat)pieChartView:(MCPieChartView *)pieChartView valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {


   return [[self.values objectAtIndex:index] floatValue];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)pieChartView:(MCPieChartView*)pieChartView didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

   testingvc *destViewController =  (testingvc*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testing"];
    self.values =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];
    // //destViewController = [CategoryVC.destViewController objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *sample=[self.values objectAtIndex:index];
     NSString*item=[sample objectForKey:@"SESSIONVALUE"];
    //
    destViewController.category = item;
    destViewController.STATUS =dictObject;
    destViewController.fromDate=str1;
      destViewController.Todate=str2;
    [destViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:destViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}


@end
```

i got the error while select the 4th slice index ...i got the crash of
2016-03-31 11:40:10.582 Yazaki[2150:37777] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
self.values=[_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];

NSLog(@"got response==%@", self.values);
int i;

for (i=0; i<[self.values count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *exp=[self.values objectAtIndex:i];
    _item=[exp objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"];
    //[self.testARYY addObject:item];
      }
    [self.values addObject:_item];
```

into and try

```
NSArray *temp =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];

 if (temp.count>0)
{ 
[self.values removeAllObjects];
 self.values = [NSMutableArray new];


for (i=0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
    [self.values addObject:[NSString Stringwithformat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"]]];
      }
  }
```

or use like

**Choice-2**

```
  NSArray *temp =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];
  if ([temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && temp.count !=0)

  {
 // value is available
  [self.values removeAllObjects];
 self.values = [NSMutableArray new];


for (i=0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
    [self.values addObject:[NSString Stringwithformat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"]]];
      }

  }
```

**Update-2**

```
if( [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"] == nil ||  
[[_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ){
 // do nothing
  }else
  {
 NSArray *temp =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];
  if ([temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && temp.count !=0)

  {
 // value is available
  [self.values removeAllObjects];
 self.values = [NSMutableArray new];


for (i=0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
    [self.values addObject:[NSString Stringwithformat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"]]];
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: ok we for step by step what the error faced at now

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds   i dot empty array

Comment: Thank u so much karthick i got the answer

Comment: @fathima -- welcome ...

Comment: karthick ...in case if count ==null ...then it will through the error  -[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21b9b48
2016-03-29 17:20:11.483 Yazaki[5050:128764] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21b9b48'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @fathima - r u facing this error in this line `NSArray *temp` correct

Comment: @fathima -- check the updated answer

Comment: s karthick  if i got the null values then its throw the error

Comment: @fathima -- check the another option also

Comment: ya i updated ur code  even when i click the 0 object its throw the error The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-03-29 17:31:17.100 Yazaki[5133:131562] -[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2183b48
2016-03-29 17:31:17.110 Yazaki[5133:131562] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2183b48'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Comment: can you updated ur question once'

Comment: karthick now u can  check my post i update my code

Comment: @fathima- try the choice no 2 once

Comment: hi Karthick i got the solution but got the error when response call null its get crashed  {"SESSIONCOUNT":null}

Comment: @fathima -- check the updated 2 answer

Comment: i fix the issus karthick thank u so much for ur help...

Comment: @fathima -- happy to hear pa

Comment: i got the another doubt karthick shall i ask

Comment: Thanks ..When Selected the pieChart slice i need to pass the another view  [{"SESSIONVALUE":"BreakFast","COUNTVALUE":"1423"},{"SESSIONVALUE":"Dinner","COUNTVALUE":"5365"},{"SESSIONVALUE":"Lunch","COUNTVALUE":"6273"},{"SESSIONVALUE":"Supper","COUNTVALUE":"28"}]} session values based on the index

Comment: like i need the pass the "SESSIONVALUE":"Lunch" values based on the index to another view

Comment: - (void)pieChartView:(MCPieChartView*)pieChartView didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    CategoryVC *destViewController =  (CategoryVC*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoyTest"];
    destViewController.categoryDICT = [self.temp objectAtIndex:index];
   
} here my code but i got the null in categoryDICT what mistake i did karthick

Comment: is not `[self.temp objectAtIndex:index]`, it is `[self. values objectAtIndex:index]`

Comment: i get the values then i can pass the values to another vc but i can't navigate karthick thats the problem

Comment: simple after this line  CategoryVC *destViewController = (CategoryVC)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoyTest"]; destViewController.categoryDICT = [self. values objectAtIndex:index]; add this [self.navigation controller pushviewcontroller: destViewController animated : yes];

Comment: Thank u so much Karthik  i fix all issues

Comment: @fathima - happy to hear

Comment: 2016-03-30 17:19:10.533 Yazaki[5040:125333] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'  again i ma getting error when click the 3rd slice index to navigate

Comment: HI Karthik can U tell me y i amgeeting the error ...i can't find the solution .....for the error...when i click the 4th index i got the error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3] help me to solve this issue karthick

Comment: check your array count once, you are accessing the greater than array count

Comment: but its a dynamic values,,what i got in the pie chart i select when i select the  4th index i got the error...there i used  and  from navigation part [self.values objectAtIndex:index] we mention like that it means no of index right then y i got beyond bounds error karthic...

Comment: can u update your question

Comment: now u can check my post Karthick

Comment: ok now explain in which line it is crasj

Comment: - (void)pieChartView:(MCPieChartView*)pieChartView didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{
  NSDictionary *sample=[self.values objectAtIndex:index];
at this point  when debug index [4] then it get crash

Comment: ya I got it In here i cant say the excat answer, reason I dont know how do u did it , ok print the `self.values ` inside the `didSelectSliceAtIndex` method

Comment: Hi Karthick i fix the issues by i change the code by looping    
            for (i=0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
                
                
//                [self.values addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"]]];
                NSDictionary*test=[temp objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString*add=[test objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"];
                [self.values addObject:add];

Comment: @fathima -- congratz sister, but I m not feel happy to see your code is correct

Comment: if( [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"] == nil ||
       [[_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ){
    }else
    {

Comment: NSArray *temp =   [_serviceResponse objectForKey:@"SESSIONCOUNT"];
        if ([temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && temp.count !=0)
         
        {
            // value is available
            [self.values removeAllObjects];
            self.values = [NSMutableArray new];
            int i;
                    for (i=0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
                NSDictionary*test=[temp objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString*add=[test objectForKey:@"COUNTVALUE"];
                [self.values addObject:add];
            }

Comment: @fathima - its ok carry on ur work

Comment: @fathima - boss I have a work , If I free I surely explain, continue ur work , no problem u carry on\

Comment: @fathima - welcome sister ..., good to hear,

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change this line:

```
return [[self.values objectAtIndex:index] floatValue];
```

to this

```
return [[self.values objectAtIndex:index][@"COUNTVALUE"] floatValue];
```

The error says that you are trying to call the `floatValue` function on a `NSMutableDictionary`, from my understanding you should call it on the value stored under the "COUNTVALUE" key of the dictionary.